# Microsoft Graph API issue when no cc or bcc recipients

Tags: c#, .net, rest, email

Constructing Email Message using REST and C# - Invalid recipients
I am reasonably new to C#, but not .NET development. I am also fairly new to Graph development.

I am trying to build the code that can be used to construct messages within my organisation. Ultimately the code will become an RPA code object.

I have a class for the message, which has classes defined for toRecipient, ccRecipient and bccRecipient. Creating and sending an email works fine when I have data for the To, CC and Bcc options. However, I get an error message if I only have To recipients and not cc or Bcc recipitents. Similarly I cannot send to bcc only, as the code is looking for values to the toRecipients and CC recipients.

> **Error message:**
>
> ```
> {
>     "error":{
>         "code":"ErrorInvalidRecipients",
>         "message":"At least one recipient isn't valid., Recipient '' is not resolved. All recipients must be resolved before a message can be submitted."
>     }
> }
> ```

How do I make the sub classes for cc and BCC optional? – or is there syntax I can use to tell the API that cc and bcc fields are empty?

I build the class based on a message created using Postman, and then using Paste Special into my message class.

> **Class:**
>
> ```
> public class gMessage {
>     public grfMessage message { get; set; }
>     public string saveToSentItems { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class grfMessage {
>     public string subject { get; set; }
>     public Body body { get; set; }
>     public List <ToRecipient> toRecipients { get; set; }
>     public List<ToRecipient> ccRecipients { get; set; }
>     public List<ToRecipient> bccRecipients { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class Body {
>     public string contentType { get; set; }
>     public string content { get; set; }
> }
>
> public class ToRecipient {
>     public EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }
>     public static implicit operator List<object>(ToRecipient v) {
>         throw new NotImplementedException();
>     }
> }
>
> public class EmailAddress {
>     public string address { get; set; }
> }
> ```

> **Input variables:**
>
> ```
> public static string EmailRecipients = "email1@company.com";email2@company.com;
> public static string EmailCCList = "email3@organisation.org";
> public static string EmailBCCList = "";
> ```

> **Code to build message:**
>
> ```
> // Define our recipient list 
> List<ToRecipient> listRecip = new List<ToRecipient>(); // define new list. We will ultimately split the inbount array into this list
> ToRecipient RecipEmail;
> EmailAddress ema1;
>
> // now split our list of recipients to an array
> string[] ToAdds = EmailRecipients.Split(';');
> foreach (var email in ToAdds) {
>     // Build the recipients list first
>     RecipEmail = new ToRecipient();
>     ema1 = new EmailAddress {
>         address = email
>     }; // Email Address class contains Address
>     RecipEmail.EmailAddress = ema1;
>     listRecip.Add(RecipEmail); // We have now added to the list in memory
> }
>
> //Define our CC List
> List<ToRecipient> ccRecip = new List<ToRecipient>(); // define new list. We will ultimately split the inbount array into this list
> ToRecipient ccEmail;
>
> string[] ccAdds = EmailCCList.Split(';');
> foreach (var email in ccAdds) {
>     // Build the recipients list first
>     ccEmail = new ToRecipient();
>     ema1 = new EmailAddress {
>         address = email
>     }; // Email Address class contains Address
>     ccEmail.EmailAddress = ema1;
>     ccRecip.Add(ccEmail); // We have now added to the list in memory
> }
>
> //Define our BCC List
> List<ToRecipient> bccRecip = new List<ToRecipient>(); // define new list. We will ultimately split the inbount array into this list
> ToRecipient bccEmail;
>
> string[] bccAdds = EmailBCCList.Split(';');
> foreach (var email in bccAdds) {
>     // Build the recipients list first
>     bccEmail = new ToRecipient();
>     ema1 = new EmailAddress {
>         address = email
>     }; // Email Address class contains Address
>     bccEmail.EmailAddress = ema1;
>     bccRecip.Add(bccEmail); // We have now added to the list in memory
> }
>
>
> var msgData = new gMessage() {
>     message = new grfMessage() {
>         subject = mSubject,
>         body = new Body() {
>             contentType = mContentType,
>             content = mBody
>         },
>         toRecipients = listRecip,
>         ccRecipients = ccRecip,
>         bccRecipients = bccRecip
>     },
>     saveToSentItems = "True"
> };
> ```